# Why does shouldPerformSegue use a string, and how do I use a UIStoryboardSegue with it instead?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

For instance, with prepare(for segue:.. I could simply pass the segue value:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let manageCaptureVC = nav.topViewController as? ManageCaptureVC {

    }
}
```

But now I want to optionally cancel it if it's triggered, and it only seems I can do that with `shouldPerformSegue`, since using return in prepare(for segue:.. does not stop anything.

shouldPerformSegue uses a String instead of `UIStoryboardSegue`. I'm not sure why this is, and I'd like to have the `UIStoryboardSegue` value.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if debug_tutorialAllowCaptureBtnActions == false {
        return false
    }
    //how do I get segue?
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let manageCaptureVC = nav.topViewController as? ManageCaptureVC {

    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I think I just misunderstood what shouldPerformSegue does. Instead, I use both functions and don't navigate in shouldPerformSegue, and just check the value of debug_tutorialAllowCaptureBtnActions and return. This prevents prepare(for segue: from running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
   if identifier == "segueName" {   
      return
    }
 }
```

Getting the segue itself is meaningless. You only need to know the segue identifier. Also, if you need to make this the decision then replace

```
if debug_tutorialAllowCaptureBtnActions == false {
    return false
}
```

with

```
return tutorialAllowCaptureBtnActions
```

Comment: Your example should say "return false" since `shouldPerformSegue` returns a bool.